# on mousemove randomize array image

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code that changes image on hover, is there a way to change it on mousemove inside the div
thankyou.

```
  var images = ["images/warlo1.svg",
              "images/warlo2.svg",
              "images/warlo3.svg",
              "images/warlo4.svg",
              "images/warlo5.svg",
              "images/warlo6.svg",
              "images/warlo7.svg",
              "images/warlo8.svg",],

i = 0,//counter
$swap = $(".swap"),//only get the object once
swapper;//setup a var for setInterval

function swapImg(){
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);//keep i under the      array length
    $swap.attr("src",images[i]);      
    i++;
}

$swap.hover(function(){//mouseover
    swapper = setInterval(swapImg,300);//call function every 400
},function(){//mouseout
    clearInterval(swapper);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function swapImg(){
    if (toggle) {
       // swap image here

        toggle = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
          toggle = true;
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: i should write the image url on the //swap image here? or nothing

Comment: try putting your code inside. trial and error. that's how you learn coding.

Comment: Explain a bit more when your answer please ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

```
$swap.mousemove(function( event ) {
swapImg()
});
```

Comment: iis working fine, but is there a way to slow down the change of the image

Comment: i'm not sure if that's possible, becoz it will call swapImg() function everytime you move your mouse. unless you create another function to toggle true/false. if true, change image, false do nothing. true/false toggle will happen via setTimeout.

Comment: I dont get it, it should be an if statment?, could you please guide me on this, im a beginer in coding and programming